# Dictionary like object in Apex

Tags: salesforce, apex

I am using Apex right now for a project(normally have Python background). I need to do some translation type conversions.

Now I am doing something like,

```
#normally I am getting these values from a callout
String usageStatusES = 'Inquilino';
String loanEligibilityES= 'Adecuado';


public static Map<String, String> getUsageStatus() {
    return new Map<String, String>{
        'Inquilino' => 'Teanant',
        'Vacío' => 'Empty',
        'Propietario' => 'Owner'
    };
}

public static Map<String, String> getLoanEligibility() {
    return new Map<String, String>{
        'Adecuado' => 'Suitable',
        'No Adecuado' => 'Not_Suitable',
        'Desconocido' => 'Unknown'
    };
}

project.Usage_Status__c = getUsageStatus().get(usageStatusES);
project.Loan_Eligibility__c = getLoanEligibility().get(loanEligibilityES);
```

Problem is `project` has about 15 custom fields and doing like this for all fifteen *feels* not efficient. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read up about [Translation Workbench](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_wbench.htm). It lets you store picklist values in org's main language (say English), work with them normally in the main language without the whole hassle but to the users in UI it'd be shown translated to Spanish and whatever else you configure. In page layouts, listviews, reports, emails, the whole lot.

Your situation seems to be bit different, you have org that's mostly configured in English but the callout results come back in Spanish and you have no control over the data source? It seems like you could still enable Workbench and use some of the built-in functionalities, it'd just have to be bit bass-ackwards...

Enable workbench (in sandbox, not straight in prod), provide Spanish translations for your picklists on Project object. Make sure your user is configured with Spanish language preference. Then experiment with describe call that pulls all picklist values:

```
Schema.DescribeFieldResult dfr = Project__c.Usage_Status__c.getDescribe();
for(Schema.PicklistEntry f : dfr.getPicklistValues()) {
    System.debug((f.getLabel() + ': ' + f.getValue());
}
```

It'll probably look bit weird because what you need is reverse match, from label (which will be in integration's running user Spanish) to value that's actually saved in DB (English, I guess). But you could use this code to build your map which means when sysadmin adds new value it should just work (as long as he/she remembers to translate it too).

Another thing worth checking is Custom Labels, maybe even Custom Setting to store the mapping (that one might be handy if it has to work even if say an user who prefers German will make the callout). Custom Metadata (yep, I realise I'm giving you lots of terms to read up)... These will come with downside that whoever maintains the solution will probably have to modify actual picklists + some other area in setup.

Comment: Well, no control over data source and eventually, in couple months, there will be more languages as well depending on the user.(Italian, German etc.) One thing that seems for sure(at least for foreseeable future) is each user will be getting their data in their respective language so using translations with couple helper functions seems sufficient enough. I will also read about other things you mentioed (Custom Labels, Settings and Metadata) as well. Thank you for your answer. Helped greatly.